# VBA- UserForm.Lable.Caption gets Error 91 Object Not Set

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

**System Description:** I have a userform that takes input on an item that is being returned. A user clicks the row of the item that needs to be returned and then clicks a "Check-In button"

**My Attempt:** I created a button *checkin_cmdbutton* on the spreadsheet that measures which item is selected by which cell is selected *Application.ActiveCell.Row*, writes the info into a userform *Checkin_Form*, the user finishes the rest of the check-in info, and clicks submit. 
This code is the event for the button *checkin_cmdbutton* on the spreadsheet:

```
 Private Sub checkin_cmdbutton_Click()
       Set ItemID = Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, 1)
       Set ItemDescription = Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, 2)

       If ItemID Is Nothing Then
           MsgBox ("ID is null, ending...")
           Exit Sub
       End If

       Checkin_Form.UserForm_Initialize
       Checkin_Form.itemid_dynamiclabel.Caption = ItemID.Value
       Checkin_Form.description_dynamiclabel.Caption = ItemDescription.Value
       Checkin_Form.checkin_datepicker.Value = Date
       Checkin_Form.Show 
End Sub
```

**Problem:** The code throws an error 91 "Object variable or with block variable not set" at *Checkin_Form.itemid_dynamiclabel.caption* and the following 2 lines. Why is an object on a form throwing this error? I can't declare these, can I?

Comment: What type is `ItemId`? Is it `Range`? And what is `Checkin_Form`? Is it a form or a worksheet?

Comment: Just FYI - there is no possible scenario, when `ItemID is Nothing`, thus your check is useless.

Comment: You can see `Item ID` finds the cell in the first column of the row of the selected cell- this where every item's ID is on my table. In short, it's a cell object I guess. `Checkin_Form` is the userform that pops up to type in the date and condition they returned the object in. @Vityata

Comment: And you are sure that you do not get an error on  `Checkin_Form.UserForm_Initialize` ?

Comment: @Vityata it does highlight it in the debugger but it doesn't show any error or explanation when I hover over it; it does when I hover over the _itemid_ 
 line, it says "CheckinForm._itemiddynamiclabel_ <Object variable or with block variable not set>"

Comment: FWIW your question is unanswerable without seeing the form's code-behind, at least the code that creates this `itemid_dynamiclabel` object.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be explicitly calling `UserForm_Initialize` - that's an event handler, and there's a reason handlers are `Private` by default: they're invoked by the event provider, when the event provider deems it necessary - in this case, when the object instance is getting initialized.

The best way to ensure the form gets initialized properly, is to treat it like the object it is, instead of storing global state on its *default instance*.

A `UserForm` class is little more than a class module with a designer and a `VB_PredeclaredId` module attribute. This attribute makes VBA create a global-scope object variable *named after the class*, and that is how this code is legal:

```
UserForm1.Show
```

Except, it *shouldn't* be.

You **DON'T** want to store global state in the default instance: that's the very last thing you want, *especially* if your form involves dynamic controls.

`New` it up instead.

```
With New UserForm1
    .Show
    'what follows only executes when the form is closed:
    '...
End With
```

For this to work, you must handle the form's `QueryClose` event, to prevent the object instance from self-destructing itself when the user clicks the [X] button.

For this to work, you must also avoid destroying the form yourself, e.g. with `Unload Me` (or worse, `Unload UserForm1`) calls - say, when the user clicks the [Ok] button. Instead, you `Hide` (or `Me.Hide`) the form, so that the caller (the code that `New`'d it up) can still access the object's state.

From the look of your code - i.e. with the `.Show` call being the very last thing your macro does, I can tell that you're having the form run the show: this is an anti-pattern that will keep creating problems every time you do that.

Forms don't implement application logic: forms *present and collect data*. Nothing more, nothing less. It's not the form's job to write to any spreadsheet, or even to know anything about worksheets.

[Read this recent article of mine](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) if you want more information about *doing forms right*.

Now, the actual problem.

```
Checkin_Form.itemid_dynamiclabel.Caption = ItemID.Value
```

If that label is *dynamic* (i.e. created at run-time), then I'm surprised accessing it like this even compiles. First, remove the underscore in the form's name: underscores have a special meaning in VBA - I'm sure you've noticed the pattern by now, of how VBA generates event handlers for a given object:

```
Private Sub ObjectName_EventName()
End Sub
```

If `ObjectName` or `EventName` has an underscore, you're *asking* for compile errors at one point or another - one day you'll want to use an `Implements` statement and discover that your code can't be compiled anymore, if you kept that underscore habit: better lose it now.

If the control is dynamic, you can't do what you're trying to do the way you're doing it.

Dynamic controls need to be accessed through the form's `Controls` collection:

```
Dim myLabel As MSForms.Label
Set myLabel = Me.Controls("NameOfTheLabelControl")
```

Otherwise, you need to keep a reference to the dynamic contols at module-level, in the form's code-behind - you could expose it via a property:

```
Option Explicit
Dim myLabel As MSForms.Label

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set myLabel = Me.Controls.Add(...)
End Sub

Public Property Get ThatLabel() As MSForms.Label
    Set ThatLabel = myLabel
End Property
```

Or better, use an actual *model* class, and let the calling code not be bothered with controls at all - see the previously linked article for details.

---

### TL;DR:

You're getting that error because your label object instance isn't initialized, i.e. it's `Nothing`. Since you aren't showing your form's code-behind, we can't really point out why that is the case, but my money is on the form's *default instance* making you yet another victim of the "hey look how easy it is!" VBA tutorials that teach things wrong.

Implement the worksheet-handling code outside the form, make the form collect data, make the calling code read this data after the form is hidden, and then make the calling code create and destroy the form instance.

Now, with all that said, I've no idea why you think you need a dynamic control for this.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this, trying to learn as I go. I'm much more akin to OOP so your answer does help. This is not a truly dynamic object, it's just a naming schema I use to distinguish what is what. I'll take your suggestions but I'm not really seeing what exactly will fix the problem. This form does not calculate, it does collect data then put it in a table.

Comment: @bbshim VBA is totally OOP (COM-flavored, albeit minus class inheritance) - it's just that it also *allows* you to completely ignore its inherent OOP-ness and write procedural code in global scope like its BASIC ancestors did. I suppose it's part of what makes the language more easily approachable. Except, of course, doing that leads to all kinds of nasty issues.

Answer (score 0):

Just shooting in the dark, as far as I really do not know the names of your variables and what they are (a few screenshots will be helpful). Try like this, if your code is in a form (as far as you have `_Click` I assume it is):

```
 Private Sub checkin_cmdbutton_Click()
       Set ItemID = Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, 1)
       Set ItemDescription = Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, 2)    

       Me.itemid_dynamiclabel.Caption = ItemID.Value
       Me.description_dynamiclabel.Caption = ItemDescription.Value
       Me.checkin_datepicker.Value = Date
       Me.Show 
End Sub
```

And try at least declaring the variables (e.g. `ItemID` etc) and using `Option Explicit` on top.

Comment: I think since the command button is on the sheet not on the userform itself, you should replace Me.Show with Checkin_Form.Show. Right now Me is referring to the sheet.

Comment: Or in fact replace all the Me with UserForm.

Comment: Or `New` up that `UserForm` instance and treat it like the object it is, instead of storing global state on the global instance.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - that's the best case, but I doubt that the OP will get the idea of it.

Comment: @sktneer - true, this can do it as well.

Comment: Too bad for my answer then

Comment: @Mat'sMug - it is a good answer, as I like the idea of not abusing the `UserForm.Show` but the efforts from the `OP` should be really significant in order to make use of it (judging from his/her question). However, man should strike for the best, indeed! :)

Comment: This button is on the spreadsheet, it says so in the original question. I appreciate everyone's work but I'm  looking for simple non-OOP help; I fully understand OOP but this is only a VBA form

Comment: @bbshim - the form is an object. Thus, you need OOP to use it. How are you gonna use it, is your choice.